# Iterating in SQL

Tags: python, sql

Given the following Python code:

```
keys1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
keys2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for k1, k2 in zip(keys1, keys2):
    # do something with the pair of keys, k1 and k2
```

How would I implement something like this in SQL?

Basically, I have about 15 lines of code in SQL.
This SQL performs some actions based on two keys it currently has hard coded into it.
Well now I need to execute the same SQL with about 10 other pairs of keys.

The simple, albeit inelegant solution would just be to copy/paste the code 10 times and hard code the keys but I was curious if there was some iterative way of doing this, like demonstrated above in Python.

Important to note is that I cannot implement the logic in Python while having it connected to a database.
It has to be purely SQL.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
For clarification, however this may be achieved in SQL doesn't have to be exactly like my python demonstration.
I only used lists and zip bc that's how I know to do it in Python.
I could have just as easily defined a function and called it ten times, passing a pair of keys each time, avoiding zip and lists altogether.

My main goal is reducing the number of times I have to write the same sql over and over again.

In Python, I'd use iteration with data structures, or functions.
In SQL? I don't know.

And I'm sorry, it's for work. I cannot post the sql.
But conceptually I wouldn't think it'd matter. It might as well just be:
        from someTable
        select col1
        where attr1 = key1
        and attr2 = key2

Comment: What version of SQL? [Some have arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html), but most do not.

Comment: Show us your query, too, please.

Comment: plain SQL is a declarative language, it doesn't use imperative constructs like looping (some versions will have imperative/procedural extensions, e.g. [plpgsql for postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql.html)). But you should learn the SQL way of trying to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish without imperative contructs

Answer (score 1):

The concept of `zip` doesn't map well to SQL. While a few databases [have arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) most do not. SQL rows have no inherent order. You wouldn't say "match the first row of table A with the first row of table B" because there is no first row.

One way you could interpret your question is using [`in`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) to match multiple values. For example, if you wanted to select all the rows whose ID matches a list of IDs...

```
create table1 (
  id integer primary key,
  some_data integer
);

select some_data
from table1
where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

And that would return the value of `some_data` in all rows with an `id` of 1 or 2 or 3.

Another interpretation is to [join two tables together](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) based on some criteria. For example...

```
create table1 (
  id integer primary key
);

create table2 (
  id integer primary key,
  table1_id integer references table2(id)
);

select *
from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id
where table2.id = (6, 7, 8);
```

That matches rows in table1 which have a matching entry in table2 whose `id` in table2 is 6, 7, or 8.

Which is to say, put those hard coded lists into tables, [temporary tables will do](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-temporary-tables.htm), and join them with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
    foo(keys1) as (
        values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
    ),
    bar(keys2) as (
        values (6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
    )
select keys1, keys2 from
    (select
        row_number() over () as foo_id, keys1
        from foo)
    join
    (select
        row_number() over () as bar_id, keys2
        from bar)
    on foo_id = bar_id
    order by keys1

-- (1, 6),
-- (2, 7),
-- (3, 8),
-- (4, 9),
-- (5, 10)
```